# Decoupling Django signals from classes that touch the DB

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have one app that dispatches a signal, let's call it `signal_x`. In another app, a `@receiver` for `signal_x` is defined, and in it's **apps.py**'s `ready()` function is the file containing the receiver imported.

The `@receiver` function has one issue though. It has a dependency to an object, let's call it `object_y`, that has in it's constructor a dependency to the DB. With the values extracted from the DB, some heavy objects are built. These heavy_objects must be in memory, for very fast computations and thus they can't be lazily loaded as it would take too long when they're used for the first time. `self.location_ids` can't be lazily loaded either, as it's used by the two ***compute_heavy_...*** functions.

Everything works completely fine until we drop the database, create it again and run **manage.py makemigrations**. Now **makemigrations** will fail because Django first runs `django.setup()`, which runs the `ready()` function of each app. When it reaches the `ready()` function with the import it will, as expected, import the file and try creating `object_y`. But `object_y` needs models which don't yet exist and thus the error. How could I elegantly solve/circumvent this?

```
class Recommender:
    def __init__(self):
        self.location_ids = self.get_location_ids()
        self.heavy_object1 = self.compute_heavy_object1(location_ids)
        self.heavy_object2 = self.compute_heavy_object2(..., location_ids)

    def get_location_ids():
        locations = LocationNode.objects.filter(level=1, parent_id=1)
        return [location.id for location in locations]

... meantime in another file

object_y = Recommender()

@receiver(signal_x, dispatch_uid="update_state")
def recompute(sender, **kwargs):
    client_id = kwargs['client_id']
    # prepare some things
    heavy_recompute(object_y, client_id)
```

Comment: Your example isn't very clear. What is HeavyObject here? Where is `object_y` used?

Comment: I am sorry for the typo, I've repaired the lines now. So object_y is a Recommender object and heavy_recompute needs the object_y. The Recommender object is not a Django Model, but it has properties derived from a Django model (in the example, self.location_ids).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common use case. Since you didn't provide so much code, it's difficult to give you a very accurate answer, but, consider this:

- In a `AppConfig.ready()` function, you should always use [`self.get_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model) to retrieve a reference to a model defined in another app. This will ensure the app registry is up-to-date if `require_ready=True` (the default). Outside a `AppConfig` method, you can use [`apps.get_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model)
- Don't create a model instance at module level (`object_y = HeavyObject()`). Note: I don't know if `HeavyObject` is a Django model or not. But in general, you may declare `object_y = None` by default and initialize the variable later

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips. I didn't know about the get_model() function. In the meantime, I apologize for writing a couple of typos in the code example. Now it's all fixed and should be more clear.